# Open Source Chat Android Application for StackExchange/StackOverflow

Tags: app, chat, android

A while back a fellow member of [Room 15 (Android)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) started creating an Android application for the StackOverflow/StackExchange chat. I recently picked it up and revived it and it is open to community work. If you'd like to help out in any way, feel free to submit a PR.

https://github.com/room-15/ChatSE

(It's in Kotlin)

Comment: Is this solely the SO chat, or SE and Meta as well?

Comment: Actually it works on all chats